# How to access the Property value of nested class in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code in an assembly.

```
      public class a
    {
        public class b
        {
            public static string obj;
            public static string result
            {
                get
                {
                    return obj;
                }
                set
                {
                    obj = value;
                }
            }
}
            public class c
            {
                string result1;
                public void invoke()
                {
                    result1 = "abc";
                    b.result = result1;
                }


            }
        }
```

I had referenced this in another application(say for eg: client app) and trying to access the value of obj

If i invoke a value by creating an instance of the class b how i can access the value it set in the previous scope without return from the invoked method?

Comment: `b.result = result1;` is a syntax error outside of any method, so what are you trying to do?

Comment: for that matter, `public invoke()` is also a syntax error, as it has no return type...

Comment: As said above, your code is clearly wrong but if I understand your question properly and what you want is accessing "obj" from a class outside "a", you can do it directly as far as it is a static, public variable. For example, from the void "test()" in class "d" (outside class a), you can use "a.b.obj = value".

Comment: if i invoke the method b.invoke() it will set a value to the property result. How can i access the value?

Comment: This question has been edited twice since I posted my answer, and it now makes very little sense (and it didn't make a great deal of sense before). What are you actually trying to do? Why are you nesting these classes? Why are you calling a method in one class to set a property on another class? What are you meaning by "in the previous scope"?

Comment: I edited since i found some code errors.  I need to access the result of a method without return it from the method. The above code is in an assembly and i m calling that from my client. Using Static i am able to access but im looking for a better option without using static. Sorry to missed this point.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything involved is public, you can access this value outside the assembly as follows:

```
public class SomeExternalClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        string val = a.b.result;
    }
}
```

Comment: so If i invoke a value by creating an instance of the class b how i can access the value it set in the previous scope?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your a.b.result property is static; it doesn't matter if you create an instance of b, or how many instances you create, there's always only one result which is accessed via the a.b.result property. There's no way of getting hold of previous results, if that's what you mean by "in the previous scope". I'm really not clear on what you're actually trying to do here. I suspect you're making something far more complicated than it needs to be, but it's hard to tell without knowing what you're actually trying to do. You've edited your question since I posted this answer.

Comment: I'm not complicated things. I already explained what i trying to achieve. I have the above code in an assembly and when i invoke a method, the value should be set to a property and can be accessible from the client. I agree using static it can be possible as your answer said but since the scope of static variable is global im looking for an alternative.

Comment: Without knowing the full details of what your real code does (rather than the example code you've posted in your question), it does look very much like you're overcomplicating things. Why doesn't you Invoke method simply set the property and *return* the value there and then? There must be a reason why you're going to all this trouble, but I can't tell what that reason is based on your question. I don't think you're going to get a better answer than what I've already given unless you make it much clearer what the purpose of all this actually is.

Comment: if im using a return type it will make the method invoke asynchronous hence will wait until the process complete. If im using threading concepts here It may result in to error. The sample code provided is an assembly and i need to invoke the method outside. Once executed the value should be return seperately to client application. I explained why im using a method like this and hope this is enough to answer my question.

Comment: Okay, being able to execute Invoke asynchronously and then pick up the result later is the key part of this that you didn't mention (it doesn't feature in your question or the code you gave at all). Instead of using a static variable, you could instead raise an event when the work is done and include the result in the event parameters. Alternatively, you could add a parameter to Invoke so that you pass it a delegate or lambda which will then be called when the result is available. I'd also suggest renaming Invoke to BeginInvoke so that it's clearer that work is being done asynchronously.